# Content Security Policy Header for Webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, xss, content-security-policy

I am using Webapi 2.0. I have added a custom header in my web.config for CSP in response header. If i am passing a javascript code, api still allows me to do so. Could you please let me know how can i prevent that?

Web.config:

```
<customHeaders>
   <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';font-src 'self';img-src 'self' *.xyz.com" />
   <add name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';font-src 'self';img-src 'self' *.xyz.com" />
</customHeaders>
```

Comment: Remove all 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' from the policy

Comment: @sideshowbarker, i have removed those kesy. 
 <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none';script-src 'self' ;style-src 'self' ;connect-src 'self';font-src 'self';img-src 'self' *.xyz.com" />
        <add name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none';script-src 'self';style-src 'self';connect-src 'self';font-src 'self';img-src 'self' *.xyz.com" />

Now i am passing below payload. Its still accepting it instead of throwing error
{"UserId":"<script>alert('hello')</script>"}